# Color detection output colors other than detected color

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm using OpenCV with HSV color model to detect colors. Detecting color is not a problem, but what I'm trying to achieve is to output the colors other than the detected color.

For example, if I am able to detect orange color, I wish to have a output that covered all colors from the scene other than orange.

This is the code that I used to detect color:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

def empty(a):
    pass

# create a windows for trackbar
cv2.namedWindow("HSV")
cv2.resizeWindow("HSV", 700, 300)
cv2.createTrackbar("HUE Min", "HSV", 0, 179, empty) 
cv2.createTrackbar("HUE Max", "HSV", 179, 179, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("SAT Min", "HSV", 0, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("SAT Max", "HSV", 255, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("VAL Min", "HSV", 0, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("VAL Max", "HSV", 255, 255, empty)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frameHSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    hue_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE Min", "HSV")
    hue_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE Max", "HSV")
    sat_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("SAT Min", "HSV")
    sat_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("SAT Max", "HSV")
    val_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("VAL Min", "HSV")
    val_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("VAL Max", "HSV")

    lower = np.array([hue_min, sat_min, val_min])
    upper = np.array([hue_max, sat_max, val_max])
    mask = cv2.inRange(frameHSV, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("Original", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("result", result)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use  cv.findContours  & cv.drawContours to create masks

Comment: Invert the mask. mask = 255 - mask

Comment: @fmw42 thanks man, it worked :)